# BreakPermittedHere char in filename

Tags: unicode, filenames

I recieved (mail attachment) a .pdf file with a `\0082` (Break Permitted Here) character instead presumably of a `é` one.

`Sciences Num<here>riques et Technologie.pdf`

What could have happened ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: sender and receiver applies different code pages.

**Example** for given characters `.\Py\mojibakeWindows.py é \x82`

```
Mojibake prove using 97 codecs
string é ['U+00e9'] Latin Small Letter E With Acute
versus  ['U+0082'] ??? Cc
[b'\x82']
é ['cp437', 'cp720', 'cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp857', 'cp858', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp863', 'cp865']
 ['cp1006', 'latin_1', 'iso8859_2', 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_5', 'iso8859_6', 'iso8859_7', 'iso8859_8', 'iso8859_9', 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_13', 'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_16', 'iso8859_11']
```

Here the `mojibakeWindows.py` script is as follows:

```
import sys
import codecs
import unicodedata
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    str1st = sys.argv[1].encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-16_BE','surrogatepass').decode('utf-16_BE');
    str2nd = sys.argv[2].encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-16_BE','surrogatepass').decode('utf-16_BE');
else:
    print( 'need two `string` parameters e.g. as follows:');
    print( sys.argv[0], '"╧╤╪"', '"ÏÑØ"' )
    sys.exit();

codec_list = ['ascii', 'big5', 'big5hkscs', 'cp037', 'cp424', 'cp437', 'cp500', 'cp720', 'cp737', 'cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp855', 'cp856', 'cp857', 'cp858', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp862', 'cp863', 'cp864', 'cp865', 'cp866', 'cp869', 'cp874', 'cp875', 'cp932', 'cp949', 'cp950', 'cp1006', 'cp1026', 'cp1140', 'cp1250', 'cp1251', 'cp1252', 'cp1253', 'cp1254', 'cp1255', 'cp1256', 'cp1257', 'cp1258', 'euc_jp', 'euc_jis_2004', 'euc_jisx0213', 'euc_kr', 'gb2312', 'gbk', 'gb18030', 'hz', 'iso2022_jp', 'iso2022_jp_1', 'iso2022_jp_2', 'iso2022_jp_2004', 'iso2022_jp_3', 'iso2022_jp_ext', 'iso2022_kr', 'latin_1', 'iso8859_2', 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_5', 'iso8859_6', 'iso8859_7', 'iso8859_8', 'iso8859_9', 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_13', 'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_16', 'johab', 'koi8_r', 'koi8_u', 'mac_cyrillic', 'mac_greek', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_latin2', 'mac_roman', 'mac_turkish', 'ptcp154', 'shift_jis', 'shift_jis_2004', 'shift_jisx0213', 'utf_32', 'utf_32_be', 'utf_32_le', 'utf_16', 'utf_16_be', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_7', 'utf_8', 'utf_8_sig'] + ['cp273', 'cp1125', 'iso8859_11', 'koi8_t', 'kz1048']; # 'cp65001',
print( 'Mojibake prove using', len( codec_list ), 'codecs' );
str1stname = unicodedata.name(str1st, '??? {}'.format(unicodedata.category(str1st))) if len(str1st)==1 else ''
str2ndname = unicodedata.name(str2nd, '??? {}'.format(unicodedata.category(str2nd))) if len(str2nd)==1 else ''
print( 'string', str1st, ['U+{0:04x}'.format( ord(ch)) for ch in str1st], str1stname.title() );
print( 'versus', str2nd, ['U+{0:04x}'.format( ord(ch)) for ch in str2nd], str2ndname.title() );

str1list = [];
str2list = [];
strXlist = [];
for cod in codec_list:
    for doc in codec_list:
        if cod != doc:
            # str1ste = codecs.encode( str1st,encoding=cod,errors='replace');
            try:
                str1ste = codecs.encode( str1st,encoding=cod,errors='strict');
            except:
                str1ste = b'?' * len(str1st);
            # str2nde = codecs.encode( str2nd,encoding=doc,errors='replace');
            try:
                str2nde = codecs.encode( str2nd,encoding=doc,errors='strict');
            except:
                str2nde = b'?' * len(str2nd);
            if ( str1ste == str2nde and b'?' not in str1ste ):
                if cod not in str1list: str1list.append( cod );
                if doc not in str2list: str2list.append( doc );
                if str1ste not in strXlist: strXlist.append( str1ste );
print( strXlist );
print( str1st, str1list );
print( str2nd, str2list );
```

**Another example** applies my [Alt KeyCode Finder](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602) script (see column `Alt0` for ACP code and column `Dec` for OEMCP code):  `powershell -COMMAND .\PShell\MyCharMap.ps1 é,0x82`

```
Ch      Unicode     Dec    CP    IME    Alt   Alt0    IME 0405/cs-CZ; CP65001; ACP 65001

 é      U+00E9      233        …233…                  Latin Small Letter E With Acute
                    130  CP437 en-US          0233    (ACP 1252) US & Western Eu
                    130  CP850 en-GB          0233    (ACP 1252) US & Western Eu
                    130  CP852 cs-CZ          0233    (ACP 1250) Central Europe
                    130  CP775 et-EE          0233    (ACP 1257) Baltic
                    130  CP857 tr-TR          0233    (ACP 1254) Turkish
                    130  CP720 ar-EG          0233    (ACP 1256) Arabic
                               vi-VN          0233    (ACP 1258) Vietnamese

       U+0082      130        …130…                  Break Permitted Here
                    130  CP869 el-gr                  (ACP 1253) Greek-2
                               th-TH          0130    (ACP  874) Thai
```

Comment: How do I interpret the outcome of your first script ?

Comment: Sorry that it could be a bit unclear. Byte `b'\x82'` is interpreted as `U+00e9` _Latin Small Letter E With Acute_ in any of encodings `'cp437'`, `'cp720'`, …, `'cp865'` (listed in the penultimate line); the same byte `b'\x82'` is interpreted as `U+0082` _Break Permitted Here_ in  any of encodings listed in the bottom line (`'cp1006'`, `'latin_1'`, …, `'iso8859_11'`).

Comment: ok I see. And why is your script named mojibake_Windows_ ?

Comment: _Based on the advice of my lawyers:_ I don't remember